# Flask + MongoDB: An "Azure Web App For Dummies" guide

Tags: azure, flask, azure-webapps

After spending many hours reading dozens of guides, I finally got into a working setup, and decided to publish the instructions here.

**The problem**: I have a working flask app running in my machine. How do I launch it as a web app using Microsoft Azure platform?

Answer (score -1):

So here is my guide. I hope it will help others!

## Steps for launching a new web app under Azure:

##### 0. Login to Azure

Goto Azure portal https://portal.azure.com/ and sign-in using your Microsoft account.

##### 1. Create a resource group:

- Home > create a resource > Resource group
- fill in: subscription(Free Trial), name (something with `_resgrp`), Region (e.g. West Europe)

##### 2. DB:

- Home > create a resource > create Azure Cosmos DB > Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB
- fill in: subscription(Free Trial), resource group (see above), account name (something with _db), Region (West Europe), [create]
- goto `Home > db account > connection strings`, copy line marked "PRIMARY CONNECTION STRING" and keep it aside.

##### 3. App:

- Home > create a resource > create Web App
- fill in: subscription(Free Trial), resource group (see above), name (will appear in the site url!),
  publish: code, run time stack: python 3.9, region: West Europe, plan: Basic B1 ($13/mon), [create]
- Home > our-web-app > configuration > Application settings > Connection strings
  click "New Connection strings" and set `MYDB` with the connection string from step 2.

##### 4. Code:

We will use a nice "to-do list" minimalist app published by Prashant Shahi. Thank you Prashant!

- Clone code from https://github.com/prashant-shahi/ToDo-List-using-Flask-and-MongoDB into some local folder.
- Delete everything but app.py, static, templates, requirements.txt
- Edit requirements.txt so that Flask appears without "==version", because an older version is there by default.
- create **wsgi.py** with:

```
from app import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

- Create **go.sh** with the following code. These commands are will setup the environment and then start *gunicorn* to respond to web requests. Some of these commands are used for debug only.

```
# azure webapp: called under sh from /opt/startup/startup.sh
set -x
ls -la
pip install -r /home/site/wwwroot/requirements.txt
echo "$(pwd) $(date)"
ps aux
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --log-level=debug --timeout 600 wsgi:app
```

- edit app.py:

  - replace first 3 lines about db connection with: (btw, MYDB comes from steps 3)

```
CON_STR = os.environ['CUSTOMCONNSTR_MYDB']
client = MongoClient(CON_STR)    #Configure the connection to the database
```

- after app = Flask(**name**) add these lines for logging:

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
    gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
    app.logger.handlers = gunicorn_logger.handlers
    app.logger.setLevel(gunicorn_logger.level)
```

- add first line under def about(): #clicking [about] in the app will dump environment vars to the logs)

```
app.logger.debug('\n'.join([f'{k}={os.environ[k]}' for k in os.environ.keys()]))
```

##### 5. Ftp:

- Home > our-web-app > Deployment Center > FTPS Ceredentials
- Open FileZilla, top-left icon, [new site]
- copy paste from web to FileZilla: FTPS endpoint into host, user to username, password to password, [connect]
- upload the content (not the parent!) of the folder from step 4 to the remote path */site/wwwroot*

##### 6. Launch:

- Home > our-web-app > configuration > General settings > Startup Command
- paste this: `sh -c "cp go.sh go_.sh && . go_.sh"`

##### 7. Test:

- Browse to https://[our-web-app].azurewebsites.net

##### 8. Logging / debugging:

- Install Azure CLI (command line interface) from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli
- Open cmd and run

```
az login
# turn on container logging (run once):
az webapp log config --name [our-web-app] --resource-group [our-step1-group] --docker-container-logging filesystem
# tail the logs:
az webapp log tail --name [our-web-app] --resource-group [our-step1-group]
```

##### 9. Kudu SCM management for the app

(must be logged into Azure for these to work):

- Show file/dir: https://[our-web-app].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/[path]
- Downloads full site: https://[our-web-app].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot
- Status: https://[our-web-app].scm.azurewebsites.net/Env
- SSH: https://[our-web-app].scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host
- Bash: https://[our-web-app].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
- More on REST API here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API

##### 10. Notes:

I don't recommend on using automatic deployment from GitHub / BitBucket, unless you have Azure's support available. We encountered many difficulties with that.

Any comments are most welcome.